# execute a batch file located in remote server from local system via javascript

Tags: javascript, batch-file

I have a batch file which is located in remote system. 
The batch file will be executed along with the arguments which I will pass from javascript.
Is it possible to execute that batch file from local system using javascript ? I will be having full access details of the remote system.

I researched on net that it can be done using PsExec but how to use it via javascript ?

Answer (score 0):

In nodejs you can run PsExec using [child_process.spawn()](https://nodejs.org/api/child_process.html#child_process_child_process_spawn_command_args_options).

Here's an example: [Using PsExec with spawning a child process results in truncated stdout](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24395544/using-psexec-with-spawning-a-child-process-results-in-truncated-stdout)